# Problems with my first INSERT TO

Tags: mysql, insert

I just start to learn mysql and I have my first problem. I checked a lot of answers but I haven't managed solve it. The question is very simple, I'm trying to insert some values to the columns of one table, easy I know, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I try:

```
INSERT INTO 'usr'('name', 'username', 'psw', 'email') VALUES ([daniel],[dani],[dani],[dani243])
```

And also:

```
 INSERT INTO `usr`(`name`, `username`, `psw`, `email`) VALUES (daniel,dani,dani,dani243)
```

But it always shows the same message error #1064.

Comment: Use back ticks \` for column and table names ' quotes are for string

Comment: INSERT INTO \`usr\` (\`name\`,\`username\`,\`psw\`,\`email\`) VALUES ('daniel','dani','dani','dani243')

Comment: Thank you to all of you, I was using back ticks for columns but not the normal ticks for string. I read the documentation in w3schools and in mysql official webpage and I didn't found it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL thinks all values that you supplied are column names in short daniel, dani are not columns of your table usr and hence error. Enter string values as below

```
INSERT INTO usr(name,username,psw,email) VALUES ('daniel','dani','dani','dani243');
```